# Fire methods step by step

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Hi how can I fire functions and methods in a queue in Objective C ? I mean something like this :

method 1 then method 2 then method 3 , Should I use `NSThread` ?

Comment: Do you need to wait for method1 to finish before calling method2, etc.?

Comment: @user523234 : yeah something like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a different solution that involved in using GCD Serial Queues and `NSSelectorFromString` method.

1st:  Create an array with your methods names

2nd:  Create a GCD Serial Queue

3rd:  Using NSSelectorFromString to convert method name string to method and insert it into the serial Q using the a for loop, etc.

Here is the complete tested code:

```
- (IBAction)buttonSerialQPressed:(id)sender 
{
    dispatch_queue_t serialdQueue;
    serialdQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.mydomain.testbed.serialQ", NULL);

    NSArray *arrayMethods = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"method1", @"method2", @"method3", nil];
    for (NSString *methodName in arrayMethods) 
    {
        dispatch_async(serialdQueue, ^{
            SEL myMethod = NSSelectorFromString(methodName);
            [self performSelector:myMethod];
        });
    }
}

-(void)method1
{
    for (int i=0; i<1000; i++) 
    {
        NSLog(@"method1 i: %i", i);
    }
}

-(void)method2
{
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) 
    {
        NSLog(@"method2 i: %i", i);
    }
}

-(void)method3
{
    for (int i=0; i<100; i++) 
    {
        NSLog(@"method3 i: %i", i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One way is to have a `Queue` or `Stack` of function pointers, then execute and pop the topmost method until no methods are left. Obviously, you can do this with an array and a `currentIndex` variable as well (increment `currentIndex` from `0` to `arraySize - 1`, executing the function pointer at `myArray[currentIndex]` each time). See [Function Pointers in Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777486/function-pointers-in-objective-c) for more details on the function pointers themselves.

Answer (score 0):

I would use NSOperationQueue.  You can set it run one operation at a time, in which case it will proceed step by step through the method calls you want.  You can use NSInvocationOperation to create operations out of method calls.